# How can I JUnit test these small serialize and json functions? in Android, Java

Tags: java, android, json, android-activity, junit

I've learnt how to unit test basic things within Android, e.g. getting and setting of methods as below etc. but when it comes to the more complex stuff like my actual code below, I'm a little flummoxed at what to do.

```
public class SurveyTest extends TestCase {

private Survey survey;

    protected void setUp() throws Exception {
    super.setUp();  
    survey = new Survey();
}

public void testGetId() {
    long expected = (long) Math.random();
    survey.setId(expected);
    long actual = survey.getId();
    Assert.assertEquals(expected, actual);
}

public void testGetTitle() {
    String expected = "surveytitle";
    survey.setTitle(expected);
    String actual = survey.getTitle();
    Assert.assertEquals(expected, actual);  
}
```

My small code that I'm stuck on how to Junit Test in the format as above:

```
public abstract class PrimaryModel extends Observable implements Serializable{
    protected void notifyModelChange()
    {
        setChanged();
        notifyObservers();
    }

    public String serialize() throws IOException
    {
        ObjectOutputStream objOutStream = null;
        ByteArrayOutputStream bytArrOutStream = null;
        try
        {
            bytArrOutStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            objOutStream = new ObjectOutputStream(bytArrOutStream);
            objOutStream.writeObject(this);
        }
        finally
        {
            String main = new String(bytArrOutStream.toByteArray());
            objOutStream.close();
            bytArrOutStream.close();
            return main;
        }
    }

    public static PrimaryModel deserialize(String data) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException
    {
        ObjectInputStream objInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(data.getBytes()));
        PrimaryModel obj  = (PrimaryModel) objInputStream.readObject();
        objInputStream.close();
        return obj;
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like a serialize/deserialize pair of methods is generally easily tested.  You need to know that a round trip returns an object which is equivalent to the original.

```
private static class PrimaryModelSubclass extends PrimaryModel {
    /* add methods as needed */
}
final PrimaryModel original = new PrimaryModelSubclass(7, "some string", 43.7);
final PrimaryModel wellTravelled = PrimaryModel.deserialize(original.serialize());

    assertEquals(original, wellTravelled);
```

You will need hashCode and equals methods to be correctly defined as well.

**Updated in response to comment**

Comment: That comes back with the error PrimaryModel is abstract; cannot be instantiated. Also, non static method serialize; cannot be referenced from static context

Comment: See changes inline.  You'll need some concrete subclass, and I shouldn't have been calling serialize() as a static method.